# Hide param value (guid) in an URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

In my route

```
.when('/user:user_guid',{
        templateUrl : 'users/profile.html',
        controller : 'userController'
    })
```

In my `index.html` within the `ng-repeat` I have

```
<a href="#/user/:{{user.user_guid}}">view profile</a>
```

It works but in my URL I'm seeing the guid has been exposed. Is there any way to hide it?

Comment: So, what is the original problem so that you want to hide it? Here is an url to my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms - it has an id in it and it's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```
<a ng-click="go_url(user)">view profile</a>
```

and then in some controller

```
//it has many possible solutions, this is one of them
//according to your config, you're using angular route provider
$scope.go_url = function(_user){
    //be sure to inject $location service
    $location.path('/user/' + _user.user_guid);
}
```

If you don't want to expose URL in browser, use service that can hold guid variable inside, and grab it when user navigates to `/user`

---

Here's the demo

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute']);
  angular.module('demo').config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/welcome', {
      templateUrl: 'welcome_page'
    })
    .when('/user', {
      templateUrl: 'hello_page'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/welcome'});
  });
  angular.module('demo').service('SecretServ', function(){
    this.secret_guid = '';
  });
  angular.module('demo').controller('Controller1', function($scope, $location, SecretServ){
    $scope.user = {
      guid: '123345567234'
    };
    $scope.go = function(){
      SecretServ.secret_guid = $scope.user.guid;
      $location.path('/user');
    };
  });
  angular.module('demo').controller('Controller2', function($scope, SecretServ, $location){
    $scope.guid = SecretServ.secret_guid;
    $scope.exit = function(){
      $location.path('/welcome');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">
  My app
  <div ng-view></div>
<script id="welcome_page" type="text/ng-template">
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
Welcome<br>
To go to private page, click <button ng-click="go()">me</button>
</div>  

</script>
<script id="hello_page" type="text/ng-template">
<div ng-controller="Controller2">
Hello {{guid}}, <button ng-click="exit()">exit</button>
</div>    
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: with .when('/user:user_guid', it still exposed the guid. I try to remove that, just using when('/user', it doesn't work.

Comment: did you updated your answer yet? I see the same thing.

Comment: @AliceXu added demo, checkout

Comment: Ah I think I understand it now. It's compulsory to init this.secret_guid = ''; ? What if I just do return this.secret_guid?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the URL parameters. And then in PHP when you read POST/GET param, you first decrypt it and then read the values. This way nothing gets exposed. I've done it for some of my own projects, and it works.