# How to rename the URL for url: '/add/{id}' to url: '/add' in URL

Tags: angularjs, url

How to rename the URL for `url: '/add/{id}'` to `url: '/add'` in URL. I don't want to show my Id in the URL. How to remove the id from url in AngularJs?

My Code:

```
.state('app.useredit', {
      url: '/user-edit/:userId',
      data: {
        auth: true
      },
      views: {
        'main@app': {
          template: '<user-edit></user-edit>'
        }
      },
```

Comment: no need for the php tag here

Comment: @user6527 did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `params`:

Like this:

```
.state('app.useredit', {
      url: '/user-edit',
      params: {
      userId:null
     }
      data: {
        auth: true
      },
      views: {
        'main@app': {
          template: '<user-edit></user-edit>'
        }
      },
```

And,

```
 $state.go('app.useredit',{userId:'u123'})
```

Answer (score 0):

To not expose the id in the URL, use a service to hold "id" inside and grab it via the controller.

[Here is a related answer: "Hide param value (guid) in an URL"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32293081/4332645)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service to `set` and `get` the `id` and then inject that service in the controller to get that id.

**Service :**

```
app.service('setGetId', function() {
  var id = '';
    getId: function() { return id; },
    setId: function(requestId) { id = requestId; }
});
```

**Controllers :**

```
app.controller('myCtrl1', ['setGetId',function(setGetId) {

  // To set the id from the one controller  
  setGetId.setId(id);

}]);

app.controller('myCtrl2', ['setGetId',function(setGetId) {

  // To get the id from the another controller  
  setGetId.getId();

}]);
```