# How to over write ng-repeat data based on selected thing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```js
var myfriend = angular.module('myfriend',[]);

myfriend.controller('myfriendController', function($scope) 
{
   $scope.record = [
       {     "id" : "01",
            "firstname" : "Mohan ",
            "middlename" : "K",
            "lastname" : "Futterkiste1"
        },{
             "id" : "04",
            "firstname" : "Rohan ",
            "middlename" : "A",
            "lastname" : "Futterkiste2"
        },{
              "id" : "08",
            "firstname" : "sohan ",
            "middlename" : "M",
            "lastname" : "Futterkiste3"
        }
   ]
  
                    
    $scope.myemp = function(x)
    {
      
    //struck here
    //  localStorage.setItem('empid',x);
   
     // $location.path('/myView');
    //  $rootScope.mydetails=true;
    //  $rootScope.addnewemp=false;
    
   }
});

myfriend.controller('myprofileController', function($scope) 
{
  $scope.myprofile = [
       {     "id" : "01",
            "firstname" : "Kristan ",
            "middlename" : "Micheal",
            "lastname" : "D'souza"
        }
    ]
  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myfriend">
    
    My Intital Profile:
    
    <table  ng-controller="myprofileController">
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Middle name</th>
             <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in myprofile">
             <th>{{x.id}}</th>
             <th>   {{x.firstname}}</th>
                <th>{{x.middlename}}</th>
                <th>{{x.lastname}}</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>  
   </table>
    
    <br><br>
    
    
    
    <table class="table" style="border:1px red solid; width:100%; "  ng-controller="myfriendController">
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Middle name</th>
             <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in record">
             <th>{{x.id}}</th>
             <th ng-click="selectInfo(x.id)">   {{x.firstname}}</th>
                <th>{{x.middlename}}</th>
                <th>{{x.lastname}}</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>  
 </table> 
  <body>
</html>
```

I have two views say

myView and myfriendView.

In myView, there is three things my firstname middlename and lastname. It is coming from backend and through ng-repeat it is showing. 
I m saving my ng-repeat data in

`$scope.record = response.data`

Now in View2 there is list of my 2 tO 3 friends.
Say Mohan, Rohan and Sohan.

Whenever I am clicking in any one of the frind name say Rohan, I m  m getting all three details of Rohan and I am redirected to view1 .

I wanted that Now myView data should get replaced with clicked friend name data.In this example It should show Rohan M D'souze where three fields are first middle and last name resp.

I m saving my ng-repeat of clicked friend  data in

`$scope.record = response.data`

Problem is, it is not over writing the old data with clicked friend data.

Help me for this.

Comment: Please list your controller and view code so that people could help you

Comment: Provide piece of code to get better understanding of you problem and to provide accurate solution.

Comment: ok I will in sometime @Slava.K

Comment: Update the code @Slava.K

Comment: Updated the code @ani5ha

Comment: Do you want that when you click on any friend data: "My Intital Profile:" first name and middle name get replaced with selected friend but last name would be of default profile ? like Rohan A D'souze ?

Comment: No that should also change according to data of selected frnd @ani5ha

Comment: I used this method. Though it works, but if you know something else then that also appreciated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293057/hide-param-value-guid-in-an-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared a working plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/1zDFB3nSFS12Eixip8rd

The general idea is to use service to share data between controllers

```
app.service('SelectedFriend', function() {
  var SelectedFriend = {
    friend: {
      "id" : "01",
      "firstname" : "Mohan ",
      "middlename" : "K",
      "lastname" : "Futterkiste1"
    } // default value
  };

  return {
    setFriend: function(friend) {
      SelectedFriend.friend = friend;
      console.log(SelectedFriend.friend);
    },
    getFriend: function() {
      return SelectedFriend.friend;
    }
  }
});
```

and then use it in your controllers:

```
app.controller('myFriendController', function($scope, SelectedFriend) {
   // ...

   $scope.selectInfo = function(friend) {
     SelectedFriend.setFriend(friend);
   }
});

app.controller('myProfileController', function($scope, SelectedFriend) {
    $scope.myprofile = SelectedFriend;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on any friend in `myfriendController`

```
<th ng-click="selectInfo(x)">
  selectInfo(friend)={
    this.selectedFriend=friend;
  }
```

Now in `myprofileController` just assign this variable in myprofile

```
this.myprofile = this.selectedFriend; // use nav_params for this
```

If you will push new Data in myprofile it will keep your old data too. So don't push just assign.

NOTE: Please correct me if i misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Its probably wrong. Instead right method would be passing secret key through service.I mention it in last comment above. @ani5ha